# Knockout binding not updating in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have been working on a project that uses knockout for databinding from javascript to html. I am also reading data from a PLC using ajax, the data from the ajax request will put into the knockout viewmodel and shown on the webpage. I am having some trouble with the updating of the data binding.
I searched on the internet for help but didn't find anything so far that helped me so I hope you can help me further.

I have setup the viewmodel as following inside a javascript file:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.hmitags = ko.observableArray(groupDataValues);
    self.Capa100 = ko.observable("Cap100");
    self.Testvar = ko.observable(50);
}
var viewModel = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And have the data binding in the html file:
`<span data-bind="text: Testvar></span>`

when I now load the html file I see the value 50 as defiened in the viewmodel, so that is working. But now I want to read a variable from my PLC using ajax that is done through a function inside that same javascript file. This is how the function looks:

```
function ReadVariable()// function for reading out individual variables
{
    // list can contain only one variable
    var HMIReadList = "&paths=MainInstance.Testvar"
    data.length = 0; // get rid of the data from the last query
    // issue the data request
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + BearerToken);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseurl + "_pxc_api/api/variables?pathPrefix=Arp.Plc.Eclr/" + HMIReadList,
    })
        .done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            viewModel.Testvar = data.variables[0].value;
            console.log(viewModel.Testvar);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log("CreateSession Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.dir(jqXHR);
            alert("CreateSession $.ajax failed. Status: " + status);
        });;
}
```

I am using a button in the html page to call this function. In the console I can see that it is reading a value from the PLC and that it is different that the initial value 50. But on the html page it is not changing. I am not sure why it isn't working I have been looking around for some solutions but have not found anything that is working.

Comment: `viewModel.Testvar(data.variables[0].value)`

Comment: Hi @Verab, Welcome.  The thing to remember with knockout observables is that they are functions that need to be invoked to get data in and out.  Assigning the result like this `viewModel.Testvar = data.variables[0].value` will result in the observable function being overwritten an no longer bound to the html output.

Comment: Thank you! The solution from @peinearydevelopment worked. And Nathan Fisher thanks for the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

A knockout observable is a function. In order to update the value of the observable, you need to invoke the function with the new value as follows:
`viewModel.Testvar(data.variables[0].value)`